# Add new instance in AWS Active directory via boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I've to create windows instance in aws with using boto.That was easy to do.

Now i'm using [aws active directory service](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-directory-service/) , **and want to create a server using boto, that can join active directory on creation(become a member of that specified domain)** and be accessible via domain credential, but wasn't find a way to do it.

How I can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this using boto at this time.  Joining an EC2 instance to an AWS Directory Service domain requires the use of the EC2 Simple Systems Manager (SSM) and boto does not provide support for this service.

[This article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-join-aws-domain.html) describes how to accomplish this using the AWSCLI.